# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de un objeto que no existen en comparación a otro?

Tags: javascript

Buen día,

Estoy comparando dos objetos con múltiples datos cómo este:

```
var arreglo1 = [
                {id:1, identity:123456,  name: "Pepito Perez"},
                {id:2, identity:1234567, name: "Carlos Perez"},
                {id:3, identity:24689,   name: "Fabián Sierra"}
               ]



var arreglo2 = [
                {id:123456,  name: "Pepito Perez"},
                {id:1234567, name: "Carlos Perez"},
                {id:36912,   name: "Jhon Smith"}
               ]
```

Hago el recorrido de los objetos de la siguiente manera y comparo el 'identity' del primer arreglo con el 'id' del segundo arreglo:

```
for(var i in arreglo2){
  for(var x in arreglo1){
    if(arreglo2[i]['identity'] === arreglo1[x]['id']){
      console.log('Existe');
    }else{
      //La idea aquí es traer los 'identity' del arreglo1 que no estan en el       arreglo2
    }
  }
}
```

Quisiera poder traer esos datos que no estan en el arreglo2 y meterlos en otro arreglo con push así:

```
var arr = [];
arr.push(
//En este caso se guardaría identity:24689 porque no esta en el arreglo2
);
```

Espero mi pregunta sea clara, muchas gracias!

Comment: Fabian, no sé cuál es tu nivel de Javascript, pero cuando te sientas seguro con la forma de recorrer arreglos y utilizar objetos, te recomiendo que avances en utilizar funciones "callback" que te abrirán dos grandes puertas: 1) programar más compacto y expresivo, para ello la respuesta de "PA" a tu post es muy buena y detallada. 2) programar asincrónicamente para mejorar la performance. En mi respuesta quise contestar exacto lo que preguntabas para ayudarte con tu problema respetando tu forma. Sin duda, al final del camino, la opción de @PA es mejor.

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo, mi nivel de Javascript no es tan alto pero estoy abierto a seguir aprendiendo saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se recorre el primer arreglo, en una variable lógica ponemos si hemos visto eso o no en el segundo arreglo (que recorremos dentro):

```
var arreglo1 = [
                {id:1, identity:123456,  name: "Pepito Perez"},
                {id:2, identity:1234567, name: "Carlos Perez"},
                {id:3, identity:24689,   name: "Fabián Sierra"}
               ]



var arreglo2 = [
                {id:123456,  name: "Pepito Perez"},
                {id:1234567, name: "Carlos Perez"},
                {id:36912,   name: "Jhon Smith"}
               ]

var arr = [];

for(var x in arreglo1){
  var existe=false;
  for(var i in arreglo2){
    existe=existe || arreglo2[i].id === arreglo1[x].identity
  }
  if(!existe){
    arr.push(arreglo1[x])
  }
}

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Eso muestra los que sí están en el arreglo1 y no están en el arreglo2 (para hacerlo al revés basta intercambiar arreglo1 con arreglo2). Otra cosa, los campos de un objeto pueden accederse con notación "punto" que es más cómoda `obj["id"]` es lo mismo que `obj.id`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y aporte, creo que no estaba tan lejos.

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener todos los objetos que del tu segundo Array que **no** se encuentran en el primero es algo parecido a lo que ya tienes pero sacando lógica fuera del segundo `loop`.

```
var arr = []
for (var x in arreglo1){
  var encontrado = false;
  for(var i in arreglo2){
    if (arreglo2[i].id === arreglo1[x].identity) {
       encontrado = true;
       break;
    }
  }
  if(!encontrado) arr.push(arreglo2[i]);
}
```

Además añadiendo el `break` obligas a terminar tan pronto como puedas el segundo `loop` y así reducir al máximo posible la cantidad de iteraciones posibles.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero me trae todos los datos del arreglo1 y yo quiero traer únicamente los que no existen en el arreglo2.

Comment: Me imaginaba que era eso :) Ahora actualizo mi respuesta. Dame unos minutos

Comment: No te preocupes muchas gracias!

Comment: OOps! he llegado tarde! Aún así (ambas respuestas son muy parecidas) fíjate en el `break`! Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta es buena también, aprendí algo nuevo saludos!

Answer (score 1):

esta es una buena tarea para resolver **en una sola línea de código** con las primitivas de array `.filter()` y `.find()`

La solución sería algo así como

```
var res = a2.filter ( o2 => ! ( a1.find( o1 => o2.id === o1.identity ) ) );
```

bufff, parece magia, no?

Veámoslo paso a paso.

---

Para empezar

```
a2.filter(filtercond)
```

Devuelve aquellos elementos de `a2` que cumplen la condición que la función `filtercond` devuelva true, la función es llamada iterativamente para cada uno de los elementos de `a2`

---

Luego,

```
a1.find(findcond)
```

devuelve el primer elemento de `a1` que cumple la condición que la función `findcond` devuelva true, o devuelve `undefined` en caso contrario. La función `findcond` es llamada iterativamente para cada elemento del array, hasta que se encuentra uno, o hasta que acabe con todos.

---

O sea que

```
a1.find( o1 => o2.id === o1.identity)
```

va a devolver o bien el primer objeto de `a1` cuyo `.identity` coincida con el `.id` de `o2` (espera un segundo para entender qué es `o2`); o bien va a devolver `undefined` en caso de que no lo encuentre.

---

Entonces,

```
!a1.find( o1 => o2.id === o1.identity)
```

es un código que va a devolver true si `o2` no se encuentra en `a1`

---

Por lo tanto

```
a2.filter( o2 => !(a1.find( o1 => o2.id === o1.identity ) ) );
```

devolverá un array compuesto por los elementos de `a2` (uno a uno individualmente como `o2`) que no se encuentren en `a1`

Dicho array devuelto es el resultado deseado.

En una sola línea de código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, es interesante conocer diferentes soluciones, saludos!

Comment: Me gusto esta respuesta, acaso reconozco el uso de ES6